# pgfplots "every quiver plot" style key?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add the same set of options to every `pgfplots` “quiver plot”.  PGFPlots provides style like `every axis plot` to add to every plot, but quiver plots are created inside a `quiver={...}` scope.

The obvious guess was to set a style key called `every quiver plot` but it doesn't have any effect. Adding quiver keys to `every axis plot` results in an error.

Here is a minimal non-working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        width=4cm,
        axis equal image
    },
    every axis plot/.append style={
        blue,-stealth,
    },
    % compiles without error but has no effect
    every quiver plot/.style={
        scale arrows=0.5,  
        update limits
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[quiver={u=x,v=y}] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[quiver={u=-y,v=x}] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as I posted it I found a workaround:

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        width=4cm,
        axis equal image
    },
    every axis plot/.append style={
        blue,-stealth,
        quiver={scale arrows=0.5,update limits}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[quiver={u=x,v=y}] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[quiver={u=-y,v=x}] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

For some reason I thought that setting `quiver` keys in the plots would override those set in `every axis plot`.  Luckily, I was mistaken.

[image: sample code output]

To achieve the interface I was looking for (i.e., an actual `every quiver plot` style), you can do it this way:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every quiver plot/.style={},
    quiver/.prefix code={\pgfqkeys{/pgfplots/quiver}{/pgfplots/every quiver plot}}
}
```

Then later:

```
\pgfplotsset{every quiver plot/.style={
    scale arrows=0.5,  
    update limits
}}
```

Comment: Christian notes that it's not as simple as that for an `every quiver plot` key.  See the [SourceForge ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/41/).